# Effect of leverage on residuals

Tags: regression, residuals, leverage

The variance of residuals in a linear regression is given by :
$$Var(e_i)=(1-h_{ii})\sigma^2$$
This means that residuals have a lower variance than the error terms, and the variance of residuals is smaller for observations with higher leverage. I see that from the equation above but I can't get an intuitive explanation of these facts. The only explanation I can think of for the 2nd point is : high leverage makes the fitted value $\hat y_i$ close to $y_i$, which means that their difference (= $e_i$) cannot vary a lot. Are there better explanations.

Comment: The flexibility afforded by fitting a regression function reduces the variability.  One way to see this clearly is to imagine extreme cases of overfitting.  Another way is to contemplate the decomposition into sums of squares: part of the error variance is manifested in the variance of the estimated regression function.  Another way is to work through the simplest cases, such as the model $y_i = \mu+\varepsilon_i,$ which you can relate to well-understood facts about unbiased estimates of variance. It comes down to what kind of explanation you perceive as "better."